# concatenate 2 dataframes in order to append some columns

Tags: python, concatenation

I have 2 dataframes(df1 and df2) and I want to append them as follows :

- df1 and df2 have some columns in common but I want to append the columns that exist in df2 and not in df1 but keep the columns of df1 as they are
- df2 is empty (all rows are nan)

I could just add columns in df1 but in the future, df2 could have new cols added that is why I do not want to hardcode the column names but rather be done automatically. I used to use append but I get the following message

```
df_new = df1.append(df2)

FutureWarning: The frame.append method is deprecated and will be removed from pandas in a future version. Use pandas.concat instead
```

I tried the following

```
df_new = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

but it concatenates all the columns of both dataframes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `pd.concat()` with `axis=0` (default) and `join='outer'` (default). I'm illustrating with some examples

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [3,3,3],
                    'col2': [4,4,4]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1,2,3],
                    'col2': [1,2,3],
                    'col3': [1,2,3],
                    'col4': [1,2,3]})
print(df1)
   col1  col2
0     3     4
1     3     4
2     3     4

print(df2)
   col1  col2  col3  col4
0     1     1     1     1
1     2     2     2     2
2     3     3     3     3

df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=0, join='outer')

print(df3)
   col1  col2  col3  col4
0     3     4   NaN   NaN
1     3     4   NaN   NaN
2     3     4   NaN   NaN
0     1     1   1.0   1.0
1     2     2   2.0   2.0
2     3     3   3.0   3.0
```

Answer (score 1):

According to https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html

join{‘inner’, ‘outer’}, default ‘outer’
How to handle indexes on other axis (or axes).

**INNER**

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['c', 3, 'cat'], ['d', 4, 'dog']], columns=['letter', 'number', 'animal'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[None,None,None,None],[None,None,None,None]], columns=['letter', 'number', 'animal', 'newcol'])

print(pd.concat([df,df2], join='inner').dropna(how='all'))
```

output:

```
  letter number animal
0      c      3    cat
1      d      4    dog
```

**OUTER**

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['c', 3, 'cat'], ['d', 4, 'dog']], columns=['letter', 'number', 'animal'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[None,None,None,None],[None,None,None,None]], columns=['letter', 'number', 'animal', 'newcol'])

print(pd.concat([df,df2], join='outer').dropna(how='all'))
```

output:

```
  letter number animal newcol
0      c      3    cat    NaN
1      d      4    dog    NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

To concatenate just the columns from `df2` that are not present in `df1`:

```
pd.concat([df1, df2.loc[:, [c for c in df2.columns if c not in df1.columns]]], axis=1)
```